# NodeJs: Promise always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

So I have the following promise that is supposed to go inside my sqlite database and tell me if there is a match. Even if the variables are correct it always returns undefined.

```
var checkLoanable = function(bookID){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        
        db.run('SELECT * FROM book WHERE id=?',[bookID],(err,row)=>{
            if (err) {
                console.log("error")
                reject();
                }
            if(row){
                
                if(row.loanable==0){
                    console.log("not loanable")
                    reject();
                        
                }
                console.log("success")
                resolve(row);
            }else{
                console.log("undefined")
                reject();
                    
            }
            console.log("End of promise")
        });
    
    })
}
```

This is the call of the function

```
await checkLoanable(bookID)
        .then(()=>{console.log("success")})
        .catch(()=>{
            res.status(422)
                .setHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
                .send({ message: "Failed to add loan: book is not loanable!"});
            
        });
        console.log("after promise");
```

The await is inside an async function and after tests I did it does wait for the promise to end and then continues the code. I can't figure out why its always undefined though.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You are not using the resolved value, try `.then((val)=>{console.log(val)})` and you don't need `await` if you use `.then()`

Comment: @axtck It never goes to the resolved value because row is undefined.

Comment: Your query seems ok, so maybe there is no record in your db with that id, have you tried running the query manually on the db

Comment: @axtck Yes I just re-run the query using DB Browser and it does return the correct value.

Comment: Could you try using `db.get` instead of `db.run`

Comment: I assume `SELECT *` would return an array not an object. Can you log and show whats the output?

Comment: @EliasIoannou glad I could help, also for multiple rows, use `db.all()` (check the docs => https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run()` is used for inserting and updating rows.

For getting a single row use `db.get()`.

```
db.get('SELECT * FROM book WHERE id=?', [bookID] , (err,row) => { });
```

At least if you are using the [npm/sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite) package.

Comment: I cant believe I have tried so many methods to resolve this and it was as simple as replacing db.run with db.get. Thank you @axtck you beautiful person <3!

Answer (score 2):

Do not mix `async/await` and `Promise` chain use one of them.

Either with try...catch or `Promise..then..catch`

```js
try {
  const book = await checkLoanable(bookID);
  res.json(book);
}catch ({message}) {
  res.status(422).send(message);
}

// or
checkLoanable(bookID)
  .then((book) => {res.json(book);})
  .catch(({message}) => {
    res.status(422).json({ 
      message: "Failed to add loan: book is not loanable!"
    });
  });
```

For the example if you use something like this

```js
const myPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Success!');
  }, 1000);
});

(async () => {
  const result = await myPromise().then(data => {
    console.log({data});
  });
  console.log({result});
})();
```

Result would be

```
{data: 'Success!'}
{result: undefined}
```

Not both get values at the same time.

Comment: Yes this is also a good point! @Eliasloannou have a look